# ECG beat detection

Tags: health, signal-processing

I am looking for a program or script that detect beat given an ECG signal. Preferably working on Windows, gratis and open source.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are looking for MNE which was originally written in C for doing all sorts processing magnetoencephalography (MEG) and electroencephalography (EEG) data. Unfornately the C build is only available for Linux & OS-X **but** the good news is that there is a new, *pure* [python](http://python.org) implementation that should run on just about anything, even Windows.

- Working on Windows - **Yes** ***for the python version*** but there are a number of dependencies see [here](http://martinos.org/mne/stable/advanced_setup.html) for more details of installing the python version.
- Open Source - **Yes** - "The Matlab and Python components of MNE are provided under the simplified BSD license"
- Free/Gratis - **Yes**
- Can process from an ECG - **Yes** see [here](http://martinos.org/mne/stable/generated/mne.preprocessing.find_ecg_events.html?highlight=heartbeat)
- Read [the Licence](http://martinos.org/mne/stable/manual/AppEULA.html?highlight=licence) carefully - the python version licence ***is*** different.
- Keep in mind the intended usage and the disclaimers on liability.

From the MNE python API:

> mne.preprocessing.find_ecg_events(raw, event_id=999, ch_name=None,
>   tstart=0.0, l_freq=5, h_freq=35, qrs_threshold='auto',
>   filter_length='10s', verbose=None)
>
> Blockquote

Find ECG peaks